# What software for recording screencasts?

Tags: language-agnostic

Can you suggest some free software for recording screencasts?

I don't need some special effects. If it lets me add some subtitles, it would be great. And even greater if it created small file size and in a format that lets me send it to [YouTube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube) or [Vimeo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimeo) without any conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of like this one:

http://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/index.html

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/. It is free and web-based, more or less platform agnostic. I've used it before, and it does the job.